# gawk regex did not work as expected

Tags: regex, awk, non-ascii-characters

I have a function in an awk script that mostly works but not if german "umlaute" (äöü) are passed.

```
function sanitizeIdentifier(str){
  debug( "san IN:" str)
  gsub(/[^_a-zA-Z0-9]/, "_", str)
  debug( "san OUT:" str)
  return str
}
```

output:

```
san IN:(Vorhalt für Start/Stopp) 
san OUT:_Vorhalt_für_Start_Stopp__
```

How can I match the umlaute or better why are the umlaute not matched by the expression?

My awk script is unicode (utf8 without BOM)  and the input files are unknown. 
Converting them to unicode also does not help.

explicit replacements like `gsub(/ä/, "ae", str)` only works if input file is unicode (that is kind of clear).

using

```
gsub(/[^_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]/, "_", str)
```

replaces the occurences but if the input file is Utf8 then they are replaced by two underscores.
Whole behavior seems to be a bit strange.

I run GNU Awk 3.1.6 on windows (from the gnuwin32)

Comment: Sounds like the characters with umlauts are within the ranges in your bracket expression. On my system, the characters are substituted. Does running the script like `LC_ALL=C awk ...` change the behaviour?

Comment: With both awk and gawk on OS X the `ü` character is substituted for me as well. And it works for both `LC_ALL=C` and `LC_ALL=de_DE`, which in fact I would expect since the locale shouldn't change the meaning of a range like `a-z`. On the other hand, when I used `[:alpha:]` instead of the ranges the locale _did_ make a difference, as it should. All of that to say that this is a mystery. One question: If you didn't know what encoding the input files are in, how did you convert them to unicode? And when you say "unicode", do you mean utf8?

Comment: @jas unknown means that input encoding may be different between different input files. I tested it with files i know. the a-z range behaviour indeed is strange. if I replace it with `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` then the characters are replaced.
Iam using windows and do not know if there is an LC_ALL equivalent... i guess that is that `chcp` codepage stuff?

Comment: @jas: No, `a-z` effected by locale. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227070/38906

Comment: Yes, @cuonglm, I see! --- I'm also seeing that explained here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges-and-Locales.html  It appears to be implementation dependent as _outside the "C" and "POSIX" locales, the meaning of range expressions is undefined._

Comment: @TomFenech Why did you deleted your answer? It works!

Comment: @hek2mgl it only works with some locale settings and to be honest, I don't understand the issue well enough to explain the conditions to achieve the desired behaviour. I'm happy to undelete and make it community wiki, or let someone else answer, or whatever :)

Comment: @TomFenech That's a good idea. I've have both German and US locale -> it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The characters with umlaut are outside the ranges in your bracket expression, so aren't matched. Character classes such as `[:alpha:]` or `[:alnum:]` should respect locale settings, so I'd suggest using them instead:

```
gsub(/[^_[:alnum:]]/, "_", str)
```

Running with `LC_ALL=C` should mean that characters with umlaut are replaced. You may also want to remove the duplicate `_` by adding a second substitution:

```
gsub(/_+/, "_", str)
```

Comment: @jas yeah I think I misinterpreted the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: but this is the exact opposite of that i want. I want to create valid C-identifier. I do want to replace umlaute with an underscore. but it seemed that the `a-z` range *does* match them and whats why they aren't replaced. Or do i misinterpret the [:alnum:]?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I've updated the answer. Does that help?

Comment: i have no glue how to set the locale for the gnuutils on windows. [:alnum:] does not change anything and now i will leave the explicit character list in the code - at least this works

Comment: directly piping umlaute from `echo halloä24d` into `gawk "gsub...` seems to work as expected. At least with umlaute. Using a german 'ß' results in output of 'á'. Conclusion: only using complete character list seems to work as expected - what a mess

Comment: I guess it depends on the locale. If you are using an utf-8 locale, regardless for which language, it will work. Tested.